# Force close error on application when button is pressed

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-edittext

So whenever I click the button on the startup page, it gives me a force close error.  Here's the class for the main.xml layout file:

```
public class ForeverAloneActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btnstrt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toq1);
        btnstrt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent frstq = new Intent(v.getContext(), QuestionOne.class);
                startActivityForResult(frstq, 0);
```

And this is what I believe is producing the error.  This class is related to the page that that when pressing the button on the startup page, you are taken to:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.frstq);
    Button startQ2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toq2);
    startQ2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent toQ2 = new Intent(v.getContext(), QuestionTwo.class);
            final EditText number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            final Toast error = Toast.makeText(QuestionOne.this, "Please insert a value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            if (number.getText().toString().equals("")) {error.show();
            }else{
            startActivityForResult(toQ2, 0);}
```

That if statement is there as on the next page, there is an EditText box.  I tried to make it so that if there is nothing in the EditText box, it displays a toast message saying "Please insert a value".  Until an integer is put into the EditText box, then the button will not work.

If someone can help, it will be much appreciated.

Logcat:

```
04-07 19:33:58.199: W/dalvikvm(362): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.kenning.foreveralone/com.kenning.foreveralone.QuestionOne}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.kenning.foreveralone.ForeverAloneActivity$1.onClick(ForeverAloneActivity.java:22)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-07 19:33:58.221: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It is the name of the Toast that is shown if no value is present in the EditText field.

Comment: add QuestionOne activity in manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you adding `QuestionTwo` in manifiest file ?
check your error - have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: It seems to be an exception error, how would I go about catching that error?

Comment: Hahaha, I found some input errors in the manifest.  Thank you :)

Comment: using `v.getContext()` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your activity in manifeast file. It seems you forgetted that

```
<activity android:name="QuestionTwo" />
```

also dont forget to include every activity in your manifeast file

Answer (score 0):

Hey have you added the QuestionTwo class as an activity in menifest file. If after adding the

```
Intent toQ2 = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,QuestionTwo.class);
```

then you must have not added the activity in menifest.B'coz it clearly shows in the log that Activity is not found. You have to declare the activity in menifest file.

Hope you'll get run your app.